# Encoding::CompatibilityError in diacritic charater validation in rails app

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3, unicode, diacritics

```
validates :first_name, :format => {:with => /^(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z\d][\w'\-\p{Word}\.\&\+ ]+$/i }
```

In the above code, I have used \p{Word} to pass diacritic as first_name, but get 'Encoding::CompatibilityError'.

I like to input 'Fábio Batista' as first_name, but getting error message "incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)"

Have spend lots of time on it, but unable resolve it.

Environment:
  ruby-1.9.2-p180
  rails 307

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

on the first line of your Ruby file.